# Problem with Android Emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having trouble getting Android to work on Eclipse, everything seems to be configured fine, but when I attempt to run my first program I just get this message:

```
[2011-06-19 01:29:18 - AndroidHello] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Android3.1' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-06-19 01:29:18 - AndroidHello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android3.1'
[2011-06-19 01:29:48 - Emulator] 
[2011-06-19 01:29:48 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2011-06-19 01:29:48 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Does anybody have a clue how to fix this, do I have to unistall and install it all again or is there some quick and simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

I guess , you havent created avd(android virtual device) against your target sdk (3.1). The avd can be created using avd manager in eclipse. Also please revert back with your code ... we can check it for problem area and let you know the solution.

Comment: i add my vote to your answer , he should create and AVD with target sdk : 3.1

Comment: The codes bellow but it's justb a simple hello world example so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. I can't run the emulator from the Android SDK AVD manager so I guessing the problem lies with my download.

Comment: Ok.. I accept that you hve the right avd. Moreover you can switch to ddms view and stop the application if already running. Moreover you can uninstall and the install the application.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your java code threw an exception, Go here to see the java log

In Eclipse go to Window-->Show View-->Other-->Android-->LogCat

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with the java code, Ieven copied and pasted a simple Hello World example from the internet and got the same result, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your android sdk environment is setup correctly: run the `android` command in your terminal. This should launch the android config UI. Try to launch your emulator instance from there and if they don't work. Create a new one - the old ones might be corrupt. It has happened to me before.

Comment: Okay, still doesn't luanch from the UI, I've tried creating new ones and that didn't work looks like I'll just have to try downloading Android again.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: what's the error message when you try to start it from the android ui?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem while trying to run my app through Emulator(AVD). 
All the Android settings were default. 
I tried three things before going ahead and changing any of the default settings or Path.

1) Deleted multiple virtual devices which I created as part of trail and error.

2) Restarted my pc

3) Created new virtual device and launched the app again through Eclipse and ADB.exe was down. So I started ADB.exe by going to C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools and clicked on adb.exe file.

the emulator took 4-5 minutes but I was able to see my App icon. Hope it helps :)